How to upgrade starting 18.04 server to 24.04 full desktop setup
I had set up lubuntu 18.04 as a server (no desktop). I was using it by remotely ssh into. However now I need to convert it to a full desktop setup.
Long story short, how is the best reliable way to start from lubuntu server 18.04 and finish with Ubuntu 24.04 desktop.
The drive is 2T capacity. and there is no time restriction to do the upgrade.
Please let me know or point me to any step by step procedure. I shall be able to provide any details if required during this process.
Thanks

A fresh install of 24.04 would be the best solution.

Suppose I go that route (fresh install) What happens to existing data/code on the machine.. Which folders will be destroyed/overwritten ... Can you give any idea? ...Sorry  I am doing this for the first time for linux

Official documentation on the procedure. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

You will have to backup all data in the home folder before performing the installation. The data in the other partitions should not be overwritten, as long as you choose not to format them during installation. In any case, having a backup of everything is always a good idea

good. this will keep me busy for the weekend. I will comment here in case I face any issue. Thanks

Don't forget there is no upgrade path for Lubuntu/LXDE 18.04 to later releases without risk of breakage due to change of desktop (as is documented). A re-install is required where Lubuntu/LXDE packages were concerned due to 18.10/cosmic using upstream Debian packages untouched from 18.10 onwards; with Lubuntu switching to LXQt. Your Ubuntu base will install as per documentation (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades etc) but your desktop/GUI will change to LXQt and you may need to fix that; as the result can be broken.  Docs on that upgrade no longer exist sorry.

Best results maybe removing all of the Lubuntu/LXDE packages... and return your system to a pure Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS, then your system is supported for the 18.04 to 20.04 upgrade path.. however you've left it too late for us to even support you with that process; as 18.04 is now EOSS or EOL (depending on architecture) and off-topic on this site.  After upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04; it'll be 20.04 to 22.04 (again follow official docs) with the upgrade of 22.04 to later 24.04 currently not yet open (15 August 2024 was date listed as earliest in docs; we're not there yet!)

Ubuntu Desktop uses the GNOME desktop (GTK4); which is very different to the Qt5 desktop used by Lubuntu (or deprecated LXDE/GTK2 desktop on your current system), so a clean install & restore of data suggested by @David in first comment makes sense to me...  For Lubuntu specifically; a non-destructive re-install also achieves it extremely quickly.. but that is not intended for Server setups which you allude rather strongly being the use of your system  (Don't forget 24.04 is open for new installs or upgrades from 23.10 ONLY currently!)

Thanks guiverc for detailed explanation.
